# how to umount /home in ssh?

Tags: ssh, umount

I would like ssh, sudo su and umount /home and run diagnostic on it.  Is there a runlevel I can used to close X and other process using /home while keeping network access?  Or another way?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, log out all user manually, then ssh with root.

Use "lsof | grep home" to find remaining process that use /home and kill them all.

You can umount.

Answer (score -2):

`/home` is only typically in use when users are logged in.  The root user has a `/root` home specifically so the root user is not dependent upon additional mount points.

**Enable root SSH login**

For Ubuntu this means you need to give root a password in order to login via `ssh`:

[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Enabling the root account](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Enabling%20the%20root%20account)

Consider that the root account may be disabled from SSH access by default, verify the setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

**Logoff users and prevent new logins**

To kick users off in a multi-user environment one would normally change to the single-user run level 1.  However this is pretty much a console or serial port only task as `sshd` by default is configured only for run levels 2, 3, 4, and 5, and that you will likely lose your `ssh` connection.

http://www.debianadmin.com/debian-and-ubuntu-linux-run-levels.html

The not so great alternative is judicious use of `killall --user` but has to be applied to each and every user.  Only the login (pseudo) terminal process needs to be killed and a more refined approach can be taken, for example:

```
skill -KILL -v /dev/pts/*
```

The next problem is prevent users immediate sign back in.  You can create the file `/etc/nologin` to prevent user logins, you need to ensure `pam_nologin.so` is enabled on Linux for all PAM methods such as SSH:

http://www.novell.com/support/dynamickc.do?cmd=show&forward=nonthreadedKC&docType=kc&externalId=7007116&sliceId=1

This is also provided by the `shutdown -k` command:

> -k     Only send out the warning messages and disable logins, do not
>   actually bring the system down.

**Finally**

You can `unmount /home`.

Comment: Instead of giving root a password, I gave it a public key.  It allow to log the same way.

Comment: However, telinit 1 also close the ssh connection and prevent connecting back.

Comment: Unless we can configure sshd to run in level 1, it is just trouble going there.